# Redirecting to different view in different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created two projects in one solution.
I have to redirect to login page of second project from first project in MVC4 after log out.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its still a different project, so it will be run on a different URL and/or Port.
So the easiest way I reckon would be redirecting to that URL from the Logout method.

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
  return Redirect("http://URL:PORT/Account/");
}
```

and if you have any URL params

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
  var someVars = "?Hello=hello";
  return Redirect("http://URL:PORT/Account/" + someVars);
}
```